# Windows phone Login sessions and session management

Tags: c#, .net, session, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app that has 2 user types and requires a login when starting the app.

I am still new to windows phone development and am looking for a way which a can manage login sessions (an the types to, one can have more than one login session but must be of different user types). That is keep record of the login (A user will only login once when starting the for the first time app, unless he/she logout) and I also want to have a pin lock when a user has been inactive (or if he deactivated the app) to require to insert he/her pin to continue using the app.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Please elaborate more it is not very much clear..

Comment: @PratikGoyal I want to store data on the user phone (login details) and other app data. ( the data will be accessible during the whole app lifetime), I also need suggestions on how i can create and manage the login sessions in windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Isolated storage to store your session data and when session ends you have to clear it.

Please see my post on the same here:

[WP7 app that saves user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149838/wp7-app-that-saves-user-settings/21159395#21159395)

I hope these will solve your problem.